# My ssh function stopped working after I did “something”

Tags: ssh

The ultimate goal for me is to run applications and their GUIs on a (Mac) computer from another computer. The first step is to just use `SSH` to access and controll the computer using another computers and the terminal. This was working fine.

The next step was to install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) on both server and terminal to be able to see and use GUI on the other computer. Regular `SSH` control worked but not the GUI-thing. Apparently the `DISPLAY` variable was not set correctly and this was probably due to that `XLForwarding = no` was set to no in the sshd.config file. I changed it to yes, regular `SSH` still worked but the `DISPLAY` was still wrong and GUI did not appear. So, I read that I had to restart the `SSH` service and I found a way to do it:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

This screwed something up, because now I can't even do regular `ssh` control. I tried to both `unload` and `load`, this gives different error messages in the terminal:

When I run (on the other computer):

```
 sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

I instantly get:

> ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Then I tried to undo the damage:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Then I, after some time (about 3 seconds), get:

> ssh: connect to host macpro-****.imt.liu.se port 22: Connection refused

What have I done, and how can I fix it? :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out we had changed the extention of the sshd_config file to .txt (don't ask me why) and this did not appear to be a problem until we restarted the ssh service using load/unload. This tricked me into blaming the unload function.

So, problem solved by renaming sshd_config.txt to sshd_config and restarting the service.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be information missing here, but if you are just interested in restarting the `sshd` process, then using the following command would be more appropriate than unloading the service:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
```

It should restart automatically.

Your usage of `launchctl unload` will actually stop the `sshd` process from starting, which is not what you are looking for.

---

To begin troubleshooting, verify that `sshd` is actually listening on your machine, as well as the target machine:

```
MacBook-Pro: user$ netstat -a | grep ssh
tcp6       0      0  *.ssh                  *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.ssh                  *.*                    LISTEN
```

Note that you can also make changes in the GUI, if you are more comfortable with that:

[image]

Comment: I updated the answer to give you more pertinent info.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I will definetly try that at work tomorrow. We were so close to making it work, then I wrecked it big time... Especially hard since I'm new to shell. The GUI looks the same as before and as your print above... Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to put in the code you gave me to see if sshd was listening to the machines. Do i put in netstat -a | grep ssh" and the rest will pop up? (it didn't). Or should I enter it all together?

Comment: Hey again. Thaks for the help. You don't have to bother anymore. Somehow it works again. I think that we changed the extenton on the sshd.config to sshd.config.txt. It worked after that, but the change was not applied until I restarted the ssh service. Then it stopped working and I blamed the load thing. We removed the extention, reset the ssh service in the GUI and now it works. Thansk!

Comment: However, can you tell me what it means to unlaod the plist?

Comment: Loading and unloading services through `launchctl` is the mac way of doing the `init.d` scripts in linux: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd when you [un]load a `plist` you are telling `launchctl` to follow the command that is written in the `property list` - in your case, it is a command to start and stop `sshd`

Comment: As a side note, you might get better answers if you asked this in either http://apple.stackexchange.com, or http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Also, if you are satisfied / finished with the question, you can select the answer, or, if what I suggested didn't really help you find the solution, then create your own answer with the steps you took, so the question gets closed as "answered," and also helps future googlers who might come here.